# Coerciveness and Positive definiteness relation?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ be  a symmetric matrix. How can I demonstrate that A is positive definite iff the function $q(x) := x^TAx$ is coercive .

I know the eigenvalues of A have to be positive for a positive definite matrix. But I don't see how this relates to coerciveness.

Does't $x^TAx$ need to be greater than $0$ to be positive definite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of positive definite is that $x^\top A x > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

The definition of coercive is that $x^\top A x > c\lVert x \rVert^2$ for some constant $c >0$.

Obviously, coercive implies positive definite.  For the reverse impliciation, I suggest thinking about $x^\top A x$ restricted to the unit sphere.  What can you say about its minimum value?

Another approach, if you know it, is to use the real spectral theorem.

Comment: BTW, the reason that there are two different names for "the same" concept is that these two notions differ for infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: do you refer to the two different definitions of coerciveness?

I was under the impression a function is coercive if it just tends to infinity as the norm tends to infinity, and couldn't see how the definition provided here relates to it

Comment: Steven - I'm not sure what point you are trying to make regarding the unit sphere, all I can think is that it has some bounded minimum value.

Comment: Can you reproduce the definition of "coercive" you have here?  I am using what I believe to be the standard definition, here for instance:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function#Coercive_operators_and_forms

Comment: I have 
" We say that $f : \mathbb{R}^n→ \mathbb{R}$ is coercive when $\lim_{\|x\|→∞}f(x) = ∞$. Or a function $f$ is coercive when the values of $f$ tend to infinity whenever the norm of x tends
to infinity.

I suspect these are the same definitions, just in a different format, which I am unable to recognise. IS that the case?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Then the constant is the smaller eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Yes, in the case that A is symmetric, this is the case.

Comment: I tried using the spectral theorem but I'm stuck: I know that $A = \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \lambda_k P_{\lambda_k}$, where $\lambda_k > 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $P_{\lambda_k}$ are the orthogonal projections on the eigenspaces of $A$. Thus $$\langle A x, x \rangle = \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \lambda_k \langle P_{\lambda_k} x, x \rangle.$$ I would now like to be able to find $C_k > 0$ with $\langle P_{\lambda_k} x, x \rangle \ge C_k \| x \|^2$, which would conclude the proof ($c := \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \lambda_k C_k > 0$). I know orthogonal projections are self-adjoint and positive and $\|P_\lambda\|=1$.

Answer (score 2):

There are several definitions that come into play. Let's take $V$ - our vector space with scalar product

A linear operator $A$ is called *positive*, if $$\forall x\in V \quad (Ax,x)>0.$$

A linear operator $A$ is called *positive definite*, if there exists a positive constant such that $$\forall x\in V \quad (Ax,x)\ge c \|x\|^2.$$

Let $B$ be a bilinear form over a normed space $W$, then we call it *coercive* if there exists a positive constant $b$ such that $$\forall x\in W \quad B(x,x)\ge b \|x\|^2.$$ Note that we don't need scalar product to define a coercive bilinear form.

Note also that to a linear operator $A$ in a space with inner product you can associate a bilinear form $$ x,y \to (Ax,y).$$ For $A$ to be Positive definite or for its associated bilinear form to be coercive is the same thing.

On a bright side, in finite dimensioned space all these notions are equivalent, because all norms are equivalent and we have a natural scalar product in $\Bbb C^n$.