# Am I Using Rellich Compactness Theorem Correctly to extract a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, compactness

**I'm trying to work through how Rellich compactness theorem is used at the start of this proof to extract the subsequence**

- **Given an sequence $\{y_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1} \in H_A(D^*)/ \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded in the energy norm over $D^*$, you can extract a subsequence that converges in $H^1(D)$ to an element of $H_A(D)/ \mathbb{R}$.**

The start of the proof was given as:
Use Poincare Inequality along with Rellich compactness theorem to extract a convergent subsequence in $L^2(D^*)$.

Some notes on terminology:

- $D \subset D^* \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (for $n=2,3$),
- the energy norm is $||x||^2 _{E(D)} = \int_{D} A \nabla x \cdot
     \nabla x \mbox{ } d \vec{x}$,
- $A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix,
- $H_A(D)$ is the space of functions in $H^1(D)$ that are A harmonic on $D$

**My attempt so far is:** Consider a sequence $\{y_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1} \in H_A(D^*)/ \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded in the energy norm over $D^*$. This means there exists some positive M such that

$||y_n||_{E(D^*)} =\int_{D^*} A \nabla y_n \cdot \nabla y_n \leq M$.

I was thinking that if I can show that the sequence is bounded in $H_0 ^1( D^*)$ then I can use Rellich compactness Theorem to extract a convergent subsequence in $L^2(D^*)$ (?).

I tried to follow what I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703652/poincar%C3%A9s-inequality-for-functions-with-prescribed-boundary) first but I'm not sure this is correct because I think I need to use the quotient space.

Next I tried to follow what I found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39141/version-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-inequality) in the second answer. I took $y_0 \in H_A(D^*)/ \mathbb{R} \subset H^1(D^*)$ to be the average value of $y$ in $D^*$. This, I think, means that $y_n - y_0 \in H^1 _0(D^*)$ (?). Then

$||y_n - y_0||^2_{H^1 _0(D^*)}$
$ = \int_{D^*} (y_n - y_0)^2 d \vec{x} + \int_{D^*} \nabla(y_n - y_0)^2 d \vec{x}$ $\leq C \int_{D^*} \nabla(y_n)^2 \mbox{ } d \vec{x} +\int_{D^*} \nabla(y_n - y_0)^2 \mbox{ } d \vec{x} $

(last inequality is by alternate version of Poincare Inequality from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39141/version-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-inequality) source)

$= (C+1) \int_{D^*} \nabla y_n \cdot \nabla y_n \mbox{ } d \vec{x} -\int_{D^*} 2 \nabla y_0 \cdot \nabla y_n + \nabla y_0 \cdot \nabla y_0 \mbox{ } d \vec{x}$

But here is where I get confused. I was hoping to be able to use the boundedness of the energy norm in this line of reasoning but without the $A$ matrix involved in the integrals I'm not sure how I can.

Once the above bounded argument is fixed, next we can say that by Rellich compactness theorem there exists a subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\} = \{Ty_{n_k}\}$ that converges in $L^2(D^*)$ (I think?). Then since the subsequence converges it is Cauchy in $L^2(D^*)$.

Is this the correct way to use Rellich compactness theorem in the start of this proof? Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you greatly in advance!

If you're interested, I'm referencing [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3041) paper.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rellich theorem. You can use that $H_A(D^*)/\mathbb R$ is a Hilbert space, then use weak convergence on that Hilbert space.

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment! I think we needed more than weak convergence for what they do next in the paper. In the proof listed they reference Rellich compactness directly so I was hoping to understand more of the details behind what they meant.

Comment: The following will be useful regarding the matrix: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115480/coerciveness-and-positive-definiteness-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bounded sequence $(\tilde{y}_n)$ in $H_A(D^{*})/\mathbb{R}$, we obtain a bounded sequence $(y_n)$ with zero mean: for every $n$, subtract $\tilde{y}_n$ from its mean (see next). Since $y_n$ and $\tilde{y_n}$ differ by a constant, they are in the same equivalence class in $H_{A}(D^{*})/\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $y_n = \tilde{y}_n$ in $H_{A}(D^{*})/\mathbb{R}$).

$y_n = \tilde{y}_n - \frac{1}{|D^{*}|}\int_{D^{*}}\tilde{y}_n dx$

Now, we have

$\|y_n\|^2+\|\nabla y_n\|^2 \leq c_1 \|\nabla y_n\|^2 + c_2 \|A \nabla y_n\|^2 \leq c_3 \|A \nabla y_n\|^2 + c_2 \|A \nabla y_n\|^2\leq C \|A \nabla y_n\|^2 \leq M.$

In the inequalities above we used the coercivity property of A (link in my comment) and Poincare's inequality for functions in $H^1$ with zero mean ($H_{0}^{1}$ has no role: we will use the Theorem of Rellich-Kondrachov for $H^1$)

Thus, $y_n$ is bounded in $H^1$ and by the compactness of the embedding $H^1 \subset L^2$, there exists a subsequence of $(y_n)$ that converges strongly in $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I think I see what you mean but I have a few questions before I award the bounty:

(1.) How do we obtain the bounded sequence $(y_n)$ with zero mean? Can you explain more about that trick please and maybe what role the quotient space plays a role in it?

(2.) Thanks for the link! So the coercivity property of A also works for the gradient of $y_n$ i.e $ |\nabla y|^2 \leq \frac{1}{c^*}<A \nabla y,\nabla y>$ ($c^*$ is from the coercivity)?

(3.) And in the second inequality again we use Poincare and the term next to $c_2$ should be $||A \nabla y_n||$?

Comment: @k12345 I have fixed the typo that you noticed (thanks) and added the calculation of $y_n$. I also included explicit mention of the relation of this with the quotient space $H_{A}/R$. Thank you for bringing this problem.

Comment: @ k12345 Regarding (2), only the coercitivity is used in the second inequality, and yes this condition holds for the gradient too as you mentioned. The constant $c_3$ has the Poincare's constant $c_1$ and the coercitivity constant $c^{*}$ in it. The constant $c_2$ has only the coercitivity constant in it.  Let me know in case I left something without proper explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed and helpful answer! I truly appreciate you taking the time to explain all of this and answer all of my questions. This was very helpful for me.